# Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors of a Rotational Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

Sorry for boring you my friends. I am haunted by a demonstration in the book.
Here is the link: http://robotics.caltech.edu/~jwb/courses/ME115/handouts/rotation.pdf

The question is mainly about the complex eigenvalue of a 3 dimensional rotation matrix. In order to introduce the angle of rotation into the characteristic equation. On page 3,the Equation 9, the author directly use the formula of the trace of the rotation matrix values as $1+2\cos(\phi)$ without any demonstration. I would like to know the appropriate way to introduce the angle of rotation.

Thank you in advance for taking a look.

Comment: The matrix is equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\ \sin\theta&cos\theta&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ (when you make a change of basis such that the axis of rotation is the $z$ axis). Thus, as 2 equivalent matrices have the same trace, you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your insight view of rotational matrix. But in some general way, could you do me a favor to show where does the angle of rotation come from, insteading using a rotation around axis-z?

Comment: All right, I think I understand now what you don't understand : the eigenvalues of a rotation matrix are necessarily {1, e^{i\theta},e^{-i\theta}} (OK with this ?). But the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues: $1+e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=1+2\cos\theta$ (by Euler's formulas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the second degree equation in the formula (8):
$$
\lambda^2-\lambda(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}-1)+1=0
$$
The solutions are: $\lambda_3=\overline{\lambda_2}$ with $\lambda_3\lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_2}\lambda_2=1$, so $|\lambda_2|=|\lambda_3|=1$ and the solutions, if they are complex numbers, have the form:
$$
\lambda_{2,3}=\cos \phi \pm i \sin \phi
$$
and, since the sum is:
$$
\lambda_2+\lambda_3=2 \cos \phi=a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}-1
$$
we have the result in (9).

Comment: Thank you very much. Since the rotational matrix is subgroup of orthogonal matrix, the length of column vector is unit, thus  $$(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}-1)^2<4$$ and the solutions are in form of complex numbers. The above deduction is right?

Comment: Yes but note that we can also have $\phi=k\pi$ so the eigenvalues can be $\pm 1$